# Equivalent of mysql_real_escape_string()

Tags: c++, sql, apostrophe

In MySQL there is the **mysql_real_escape_string** function.
Is there an such for MS SQL to correctly handle strings like this one?
*SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Phrase='Mr Charlie's dog's dog and Mrs Molly's cat's cat plus Chris' bicycle' AND Item='wood';*

I use Microsoft SQL

```
#include <sqlext.h>
#include <sqltypes.h>
#include <sql.h>
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than composing a query as a string, write a parameterised query and supply whatever string as the parameter.

You don't say what sql library you use, but it'd look something like [this](https://libpqxx.readthedocs.io/en/6.4/a01480.html)

```
void prepare_find(pqxx::connection_base &c)
{
  c.prepare(
        "find",
        "SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE Phrase = $1 AND Item = $2");
}

pqxx::result execute_find(
  pqxx::transaction_base &t, std::string phrase, std::string item)
{
  return t.exec_prepared("find", phrase, item);
}
```

Comment: Regarding libraries, see my edited question above

Comment: @StureS I'd advise using a C++ library that wraps that, you aren't writing C

Comment: No, I am writing in C++, it's working well. I will do "parameterizing" by escaping apostrophes in each string (surrounded by " ") before building the SQL string with them. This is not a public database so there is no danger of SQL injects.

Comment: @StureS `<sql.h>` is a C header. You *can* call it from C++, but there are better alternatives. Ones that know what `std::string` is, for a start.

Comment: I don't care what sql.h is based on as long as it serves my needs. I use std::string and std::vector in my code.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Although  you didn't provide me with an answer to my particular problem, I must add that you hinted me in the right direction to find a working solution for me.